# Error "Could not find driver" laravel

Tags: laravel, ubuntu-16.04

I have 2 applications of Laravel. Both have CRUD. But one of the application is giving the error as "Could not find Driver". The other one is working fine.

Comment: Please provide more information. When you say they have CRUD do you just mean that you've implemented CRUD or you've installed a specific package? What driver couldn't be found? Does this happen all the time or only when you hit specific routes? Are both apps on the same server? Have you installed something in one app that you haven't in another? etc.

Comment: @RossWilson I dont have any specific package i have coded it. SQL Driver could not be found. and as i said I have 2 applications one of them is working fine but the other is having the error. Both the apps are same. No differences.

Comment: Ok. What database driver should it be using??

Comment: I am just trying to retrieve all the records available in the Category table

Comment: @RossWilson "could not find driver (SQL: select * from `categories`)" This is the actual error statement i am getting

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/php-artisan-migrate-gives-me-an-error-could-not-find-driver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had 2 different versions of PHP running for both the projects thats why there was a problem. Now its working fine